# Listing multiple events with sub-events on a page

Tags: tables, data

I have a fairly large collection of martial arts events that I'm listing on a page.

Each event happened on a given date and in a given location (country, state, city).

Each event has one or more tournaments, which has a division, the number of fights and the number of unique fighters.

When I had much fewer events I simply listed the events in chronological order with a heading for each year, a smaller heading for the event country, date and name, and the event's tournaments as a list below that heading.

Now that I am dealing with hundreds of events this has become a pretty bad way of displaying the results, so I'm wondering about what would be a better way to display all this data.

The naive implementation would be to use a large table for everything. The benefits of that would be that it's open to sorting, filtering, etc. but it would also mean a lot of redundant data (event name and year repeated over and over) or empty cells.

I've tried googling for existing examples, but I've been unable to find anything that matches what I'm looking for.

Here's an example of the current layout, which really struggles when there are hundreds of events:

[image: Current layout]

And here's an example of the naive implementation where everything's in the same table. This has a lot of repeated information since each tournament now gets a separate line:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Is the image you posted what you want it to look like,? What are the problems with it? Furthermore: what are your user actions? E.g. "search for / filter by date, by name", Find "Upcoming Events", "Events around the 5th of may"?

Comment: The image is of what I have now, which doesn't work now that there are hundreds of events. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: All the events are in the past, so the user actions are limited to searching by name, country or date to see if an event happened and what info I have stored about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do it by yourself and show alternatives that you tried.

I did a fast wireframe for you to think about.

On my example, I just reorganize grouping by year, month and ordinate by days. I mixed countries because it's easier to find by date and if you need to see by the country you just make a filter on the results.

[image]

---

**EDITED**

Please observe that this is not a design is just a wireframe and you should work on it to looks nice.

If I understood you are looking for something like this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The overall grouping and  filter looks great, but it doesn't address the main issue, which is how to structure the two "levels" of information, I.E. the one-to-many relationship of events and tournaments. In my example screenshot you can see that the event "WEIRD Open 2019" event had 5 distinct tournaments as part of the events, and displaying that in a useful way is what I'm having an issue wrapping my head around.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and show at least one extra alternative that you've tried and then I can redo my suggestion.

Comment: Done. I added an example of how it looks if you just stuff all the info into a single table, with the redundancies that entails.

Comment: I think that my 2 new suggestions could help you.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure I'm understanding you correctly: In your last example, you're thinking that you don't show any tournament info until you click to expand, right?

Comment: Yes, this keeps the screen clean and easy to find all stuff. Showing just when the click happens you put the focus on whats matter. If this helps you, please check as the right answer and if you really like vote up, please. Thank you.

Comment: And I suggested it because is a lot of information to show in a simple list. You definitely should group, filter and use show/hide. But of course, you can use it differently as is better for your user.